# Отправить изображение в другое приложение

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

Пытаюсь реализовать кнопку "поделиться". Необходима возможность отправлять картинку.

Вот, что я делаю:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

File outputDir = context.getCacheDir();
File outputFile = null;
try {
    outputFile = File.createTempFile("temp_", ".jpg", outputDir);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
try {
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);

try {
    fileOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, 
getResources().getText(R.string.send_via)));
```

однако получаю сообщение о том, что невозможно загрузить изображение. В чем дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение моей проблемы:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

File outputDir = new File(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/images");

if (!new File(outputDir.getAbsolutePath()).exists()) {
    File file = new File(outputDir.getAbsolutePath());
    file.mkdir();
}

File outputFile = null;
try {
    outputFile = File.createTempFile("temp_", ".jpg", outputDir);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
try {
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);

try {
    fileOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri outputUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, AUTHORITY, outputFile);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, outputUri);
shareIntent.setDataAndType(outputUri, "image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_via)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Права выдайте:

```
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Плюс, делать это надо вроде как через `FileProvider`.

То есть:

1. Добавить это `shareIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));`.
2. Убрать это `shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");`.
3. В манифест прописать это:

   ```
       <manifest>
           ...
           <application>
               ...
               <provider
                   android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                   android:authorities="com.example.myapp.fileprovider"
                   android:grantUriPermissions="true"
                   android:exported="false">
                   <meta-data
                       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                       android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
               </provider>
               ...
           </application>
       </manifest>
   ```
4. Создать файл `res/xml/filepaths.xml`:

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <cache-path name="shared_images" path="images/"/>
       </paths>
   ```
5. Ссылку на файл так получать:

   ```
       File imagePath = new File(context.getCacheDir());
       File newFile = new File(imagePath, "image.jpg");
       Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.app.fileprovider", newFile);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [OmegaIntentBuilder](https://github.com/Omega-R/OmegaIntentBuilder)

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

OmegaIntentBuilder.from(context)
        .share()
        .bitmap(bitmap)
        .createIntentHandler()
        .chooserTitle(R.string.send_via)
        .startActivity();
```