# Не отправляется (не вкладывается в почту) изображение

Tags: android, delphi, android-intent

Не могу прикрепить изображение. Ошибку не выдает, но и не прикрепляет изображение.
Что не так? Куда смотреть
D10.4,  SDK 25

```
procedure TfmDecoder.SendEmail();
{$IF DEFINED(ANDROID)}
 var
  files: Tfile;
  lIntent: JIntent;
  lJRecipient: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
  lURI: Jnet_Uri;
  lJFile: JFile;
  lFileName: string;
  lFilePath: string;
{$ENDIF}


begin
 lFileName := concat('MyPicture' ,'.jpg') ;
 lFilePath := System.IOUtils.TPath.GetPublicPath;
 lFilePath := System.IOUtils.Tpath.Combine(lFilePath, lFileName) ;
 Surf:=TBitMapSurface.Create;
   SaveParams.Quality:=100;
 try
   Surf.Assign(imResult.Bitmap);
 // Save file
   TbitMapCodecManager.SaveToFile(lFilePath, Surf, @SaveParams);
 finally
   Surf.Free;
 end;
{$IF DEFINED(ANDROID)}
  lJRecipient:= TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
  lJRecipient.Items[0]:= StringToJString('aaaa@bbb.com');

  lIntent:= TJIntent.Create;

  lIntent.setType(StringToJString('message/rfc822'));
  lIntent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND);
  lIntent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, lJRecipient);
  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString('Subj'));
  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString(AllSub));


  lIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_FROM_STORAGE,
    TJParcelable.Wrap(TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(
        TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(lFilePath)))));
  lIntent.setType(StringToJString('vnd.android.cursor.dir/email'));
  try
    TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(lIntent);
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Label1.Caption:= E.Message;
    end;
  end;
  Files.Delete(lFilePath);
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: Видимо ANDROID определена? В режиме отладки пройтись по всей цепочке, определить где теряются данные.

Comment: Нашел вот тут нечто похожее.
Не знаю как это прикрутить к Делфи. Если не сложно, подскажите.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/762534/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5?rq=1

Comment: URI нужно передавать а не само изображение через Intent.EXTRA_STREAM

Comment: @Style-7 Да, попробовал через FileProvider передать.... Дык теперь URI (вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76357675/please-help-me-understand-where-is-the-error-filed-to-find-configured-root-the) не могу сформировать. Думаю ошибка в пути на картинку.... Как ее поправить не знаю. Я еще сильно "зеленый" в Андроиде.
Если вдруг окажется возможность, гляньте что я в путях намутил? И спасибо за ответ

Comment: Сначала сохраните картинку через ContentResolver.insert он вернет URI (естественно нельзя сохранять во внутреннем хранилище)

Comment: Решено здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76357675/please-help-me-understand-where-is-the-error-filed-to-find-configured-root-the/76380668#76380668